# How to return a Firebase timestamp from a cloud function

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a Firebase Cloud Function from an iOS app. It works as expected but how do I return a value from my cloud function that's read as a `FIRTimestampValue` from iOS?

Firebase does this for Firestore documents. If I get a Firestore document with a timestamp value, it's returned as a dictionary object just like a cloud function result but the timestamp values are encoded as `FIRTimestamp` objects.

I would like to know if I need to do any special encoding on the server side to make this happen or if there is some other Firebase function in the iOS SDK to parse the result from the cloud function so that timestamp values will be encoded as `FIRTimestamp` objects.

Here is an example.

Javascript (Cloud Function):

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var dateText = "2020-10-29T21:17:51Z";
    return {"myDate": Date.parse(dateText)}
});
```

iOS (App):

```
FIRFunctions *functions = [FIRFunctions functions];
FIRHTTPSCallable *function = [functions HTTPSCallableWithName:@"myFunction"];
[function callWithObject:@{} completion:^(FIRHTTPSCallableResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSDictionary *data = result.data;

    // How do I get this to be a FIRTimestamp?
    FIRTimestamp *timestamp = data["myDate"]; 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Callable functions only return raw JSON objects to the caller.  JSON can only contain objects, arrays, strings, numbers, booleans, or null.  It's up to the caller to translate whatever is in the resulting object to the native data types it wants to use.  You won't be able to get a `FIRTimestampValue` directly from the function.

Instead, your function should convert the timestamp to some normalized form (for example, milliseconds since epoch), then convert that number into a `FIRTimestampValue` in the client app.

Comment: How is this handled with Firestore documents? They return a dictionary but with FIRTimestamp values.

Comment: You will get a serialized version of a JavaScript Timestamp object, which will show up in JSON as an object with two fields.  You probably do no want to depend on that, as it's an internal representation.  People get hung up on that a lot on Stack Overflow.  You really should serialize it yourself.

Comment: When I get a FIrestore document the iOS SDK returns timestamp values from FIRTimestamp objects. Does this happen on the server side or the client SDK? I want to do the same thing. Why should I write this code myself when Firebase already does it.

Comment: You can try whatever you want.  If you have code that isn't working the way you expect, post that in another question.  I've explained how callables work here, and I think you'll find it consistent in your own code.

Comment: I don't really have a new answer - normalize the timestamp before you send it.  It's not very hard, just take the numbers out of the timestamp and construct an object to send.  There is nothing that will do this for you automatically - you need to write the code on both ends for the conversion.

Comment: I wasted a huge amount of time because of this specific behaviour that does not seem to be explained enough or at all in the documentation